# Volley image caching system not working

Tags: java, android, listview, caching, android-volley

I was creating a custom list view app from the `Android Hive` tutorial at
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/
that uses the Volley Library to make network calls and which uses its powerful image caching mechanism.

But when I restart this application all the images cached are deleted and all of them are loaded once again into the app. What is this problem? Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Volley is powerful, but it does not handle caching on its own. You have to manually set it up. I don't know if the tutorial you linked points this out. You should think about using Glide or Picasso, which do cache out of the box